# Delete any row which has a non-unique timestamp

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I am stuck on a bit of code for my dissertation which is due in a few days so help would be really appreciated.

I have a NumPy array that looks like this:

```
[['2017-01-30T06:00:00.000000000', 48.67, 55.04],
['2017-01-30T06:00:00.000000000', 49.55249735, 55.04],
['2017-01-30T07:00:00.000000000', 48.67262295, 55.04],
['2017-01-30T08:00:00.000000000', 48.67262295, 55.04],
['2017-01-30T08:00:00.000000000', 48.55544345, 55.04],
['2017-01-30T09:00:00.000000000', 48.67262295, 55.04]...
```

I am trying to check the timestamp of each row, and if any timestamp appears more than once, I want to remove all rows which have that timestamp. So the resulting array would look like this:

```
[['2017-01-30T07:00:00.000000000', 48.67262295, 55.04],
['2017-01-30T09:00:00.000000000', 48.67262295, 55.04]...
```

i.e. the rows at 6am and 8am are deleted because they appear more than once.

I have tried using `np.unique` but cannot get this to work. I have also tried looping through the array and checking if the timestamp is equal to the previous timestamp, and then delete both of these however that does not work if there is a third or more instance of the same timestamp.

I am really stuck for time so any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

The code I have tried so far is this:

```
def del_duplicate_rows(data):
  date_times = []
  for d in data:
    date_times.append(d)
    if len(date_times) > 1:
      if date_times[d] == date_times[d-1]:
        data = np.delete(data, d, axis=0)
        data = np.delete(data, d-1, axis=0)
  return data
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a numpy array? From what I understand, ndarray must be homogoneous. That is every element must be the same type, either float or string, but not mixed. This looks more like a native python list than a ndarray

Comment: You say that you tried multiple things yourself. You should show the code for what you tried and explain what happens for each attempt.

Comment: On top of what CodeApprentice said, are these timestamps given in sorted order?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark thanks for quick response! Yes, they are in sorted order.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am new to Python so get confused with lists and np arrays - but I have created this array using np.concatenate(arr1, arr2, arr3) and each of arr1, arr2 and arr3 were created by using df.to_records() on a pandas dataframe. So I do believe they are numpy arrays. I will post a code snippet now. Thanks

Comment: If you have the data in a pandas df, you can use `drop_duplicates` on that.

Comment: @fsimonjetz thank you! That should do exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: @JohnSmith I see now. This is a 1D numpy array. Each element of that array is a python list. This satisfies the homogeneity of the numpy array since it isn't a 2D array as I was originally thinking.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice oh, that makes a lot of sense! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

No need for `pandas` or `numpy`. All you need is Python's built-in `itertools`:

```py
import itertools

groups = list(list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(data, lambda x: x[0]))

result = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(group for group in groups if len(group) == 1))
print(result)
```

With the given data, this outputs:

```py
[['2017-01-30T07:00:00.000000000', 48.67262295, 55.04],
['2017-01-30T09:00:00.000000000', 48.67262295, 55.04]]
```

---

**Explanation:**

Since the timestamps are sorted, we can use `.groupby()` to group entries with the same timestamp together into one list.

Then, we iterate over these groups, retaining those with only one entry. Then, we flatten the remaining one-entry group lists using `chain.from_iterable()` to obtain our desired result.

Answer (score 2):

For finding unique values and counting them you can use `np.unique(..., return_counts=True, return_index=True)` then you can find values that `count == 1` then find the index and return the original array from finding index like below:

```
a = np.array([['2017-01-30T06:00:00.000000000', 48.67, 55.04],
['2017-01-30T06:00:00.000000000', 49.55249735, 55.04],
['2017-01-30T07:00:00.000000000', 48.67262295, 55.04],
['2017-01-30T08:00:00.000000000', 48.67262295, 55.04],
['2017-01-30T08:00:00.000000000', 48.55544345, 55.04],
['2017-01-30T09:00:00.000000000', 48.67262295, 55.04]], dtype='object')

unq, idx, cnt =  np.unique(a[:,0], return_index=True, return_counts=True)
out = a[idx[cnt==1]]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[['2017-01-30T07:00:00.000000000' 48.67262295 55.04]
 ['2017-01-30T09:00:00.000000000' 48.67262295 55.04]]
```

Comment: Numpy.unique has parameter `'return_index'` to get indexes of uniques elements. More strait than check if `'return_counts' == 1`

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to have the data in a pandas dataframe already, you can do

```py
df.drop_duplicates(subset='date', # or whatever the first column is called
                   keep=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using numpy.unique:

```
import numpy
data = numpy.array([
    ['2017-01-30T06:00:00.000000000', 48.67, 55.04],
    ['2017-01-30T06:00:00.000000000', 49.55249735, 55.04],
    ['2017-01-30T07:00:00.000000000', 48.67262295, 55.04],
    ['2017-01-30T08:00:00.000000000', 48.67262295, 55.04],
    ['2017-01-30T08:00:00.000000000', 48.55544345, 55.04],
    ['2017-01-30T09:00:00.000000000', 48.67262295, 55.04]
], dtype='object')
result = data[numpy.unique(data[::, 1], return_index=True)[1]].tolist()
```

Result:

```
[
    ['2017-01-30T08:00:00.000000000', 48.55544345, 55.04], 
    ['2017-01-30T06:00:00.000000000', 48.67, 55.04], 
    ['2017-01-30T07:00:00.000000000', 48.67262295, 55.04], 
    ['2017-01-30T06:00:00.000000000', 49.55249735, 55.04]
]
```